# (Latin) Set apart for God

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin

The Vulgate Romans 1:1 reads

> Paulus servus Christi Iesu vocatus apostolus segregatus in evangelium Dei
>
> Paul, a servant of Christ Jesus, called to be an apostle and set apart for the gospel of God

If I wanted to say "Set apart for God" would that be "Segregatus in Deus"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the thing set apart. If you're talking about yourself (assuming you're male), you could say *segregatus*. If the subject is female, it would be *segregata*, and if it's an undetermined object, *segregatum*. Nouns all have gender, though, so if it's referring to e.g. a book, name, or house, it would all be different. Same with whether you're referring to one thing or many.

Doing something *for* another typically gives the dative case, which for *Deus* is a simple *Deo*. More clarification on what's being segregating will yield you the full phrase.

The "in evangelium" here is translating *εἰς εὐαγγέλιον*; εἰς + acc. can denote purpose in obtaining that object, which works less well in Latin and especially with *segregatus*.

Comment: Thank you all for the input ! Splendid ! It would be a motto regarding a male person, set apart (from from family, friends, regular life, etc) for God. So that would be Segregatus in Deo?

Comment: Or just Segregatus Deo as suggested by Tom Cotton?

Comment: @user1988 The latter: *Segregatus Deo*.

Comment: You are close to 20k, sir. Congratulations!

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that *in Deum* doesn't work here. In the phrase *in evangelium*, the preposition *in* means 'for' in the sense of 'for the purpose of.' Although *evangelium* can be a purpose for which a person can be set aside, I'm not sure that *Deus* by itself is. A glance (a very quick one, I admit) in the dictionary didn't show any analogous use of a sentient or divine being as the object of *in* when it has this meaning. I'd be more inclined to say *segregatus Deo*, using a dative.

Comment: I just assumed it was Vulgate wonkery.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer. Well, I wouldn't rule that out completely...

Comment: @C.M.Weimer hahaha. I wouldn't know. Were they wonky translators ?

Comment: @user1988 As I pointed out, it's probably strictly adhering to the Greek here. cnread is right on the money, though, that because it's a bit weird, reverting to the dative case is more likely, so as he suggests (and I guess you accepted) *segregatus deo*. Tom Cotton's alternative is also viable, though I at first would have read it as "set apart on behalf of god."

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit tricky, but I'd settle for [*apostolus*] *pro Deo segregatus*, which I would interpret as 'set apart for God['s work]'.

Comment: Pro Segregatus Deo. That's a marvelous suggestion, and is mighty sonorous. In this particular case I have to keep as close to the Vulgate as possible **and** I'm pressed for space, so as good as it sounds I'll go without the Pro if I possibly can - as much as I like it. Thanks so much for a fantastic suggestion !